# How to allow access to Assets File Manager but no other modules

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets, file-manager

I want a member group of "Editors" to be able to use the Assets file manager directly but can't find a permissions combination that allows access to only Assets.
You have to give them access to Modules and even if you only give them Module Access Privileges to Assets they can still see and uninstall other modules.

I don't know if there is something Assets could do that would allow a top menu button to be added and allow access to the Assets File Manager and no other modules or if it's an ExpressionEngine core function that needs to allow it.

I'm using the RogEE addon ([Show Me My Assets!](http://rog.ee/show_me_my_assets)) to hijack some of the links to the native EE File Manager but it doesn't override the file manager link from the File upload preferences and sync pages and I can't see how to hide the links to File upload and Watermark preferences from the Content drop down menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to access Modules, and the ability to install/remove modules are two separate group permissions. You can grant the former permission without granting the latter.